# Metalsmith static site generator: How to make the URL of the page: one/two/three?

Tags: metalsmith

How to make the URL of the page: one/two/three? This work must be done via a `url` variable in the template. I use [metalsmith-permalinks plugin](https://github.com/segmentio/metalsmith-permalinks). I have it hooked up and the pattern is specified as `:url`.

Later in the template write the url: `hello/world`.  But the web address of this page is converted into a `hello-world`.

How to make the page address, type `hello/world` ?

Answer (score 2):

Option `:url` will replace all characters `/` on `-`. Probably the only way in this situation at the moment - create the directory `hello/world`, and add  Metalsmith template file. I had a similar problem and solved it this way.